# Does anybody know of an efficient algorithm that removes unconnected single edges from a edgelist

Tags: sql, pyspark, graph-theory, connected-components

I've got an directed graph where I have a large number of unconnected edges, essential, both the source and destination appear a single time in the data set. In more graph theory terms, removing one of these edges from the dataset decreases the number of connected components by 1. I'm trying to find an algorithm that might be more efficient than what I'm currently doing in preprocessing(distributed environment), which the pseudo code is:

```
Group By Count Sources
Group By Count Destinations
Join SourceCount and DestCount to edgelist
Filter on edges where (SourceCount + DestCount) > 1
```

Anybody know of a more efficient way of doing this?